# Latin names of European places

Tags: resources, naming

The novel I am writing is set in Europe. For the setting, I'd need to find the Latin names of places, e.g. villages and geographical features, in the regions corresponding to modern-day England and Germany.

I am very flexible on the time period in which the names were in use (e.g. Latin names surviving the Roman occupation into any part of the Middle Ages are still fine). I am more interested in the highest resolution that is achievable. For instance, names of minor villages, or hills, or streams of water, or smaller gulfs.

Is there an online resource that contains this information?

Comment: Tgis may be more suited to history.se

Comment: This is a fine question.  I just don't see how it belongs on Writing.  History.SE is also my recommendation.  Do you mean Roman names?

Comment: Why Latin? A lot of the place names in England were in English. For example, there was once at least one ["Syvthe lane"](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/middle-english-dictionary/dictionary/MED40588/track?counter=2&search_id=349476) (or similar) in London.

Comment: During the Roman occupation all place names were Latin with locals holding on to the original name. Londinium was one example. I doubt that the Romans spent much time naming streams, though.

Comment: @Radashan It is not unthinkable that during the Roman occupation they named every geographical feature needed to get a good orientation. Streams and hills included.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it turns out, Wikipedia has your answer:

- [List of Latin place names in Continental Europe, Ireland and Scandinavia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Latin_place_names_in_Continental_Europe,_Ireland_and_Scandinavia)
- [List of Roman place names in Britain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Roman_place_names_in_Britain)

Wikipedia also has the "external links" section for more details.

Comment: +1 for the external links section.